# how to disable previous date in yii datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I am using datepicker in yii and I want to disable the previous dates on the calendar to avoid picking them.

Here's my code:

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
       'model'=>$model,
       'attribute'=>'arrival_date_as_per_recorded_travel',
       'name'=>'arrival_date_as_per_recorded_travel',
       'value'=>$eta_date_formatted,

       // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
       'options'=>array(
           'startDate'=>date("yy-mm-dd"),
           'showAnim'=>'fold',
           'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
           'changeMonth'=>'true',
           'changeYear'=>'true',
           'yearRange'=>'2013:2100',),

       'htmlOptions'=>array(
           'id'=>'arrival_date_as_per_recorded_travel',
           'style'=>'height:20px;width:150px',
           'value'=>$eta_date_formatted,
           'onblur'=>'if(this.value=="")this.value=""'
                        ),
   ));
```

Answer (score 3):

As for Yii2 (added this as answer as the question is not tagged under yii 1.x)

```
<?php 
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
?>

<?=
DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'to_date',
    'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'minDate' => 0
    ]
])
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your **options** with the following code

```
  'options'=>array(
       'startDate'=>date("yy-mm-dd"),
       'minDate'=>'0',  // this will disable previous dates from datepicker
       'showAnim'=>'fold',
       'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
       'changeMonth'=>'true',
       'changeYear'=>'true',
       'yearRange'=>'2013:2100',),
```

**'minDate'=>'0'** will disable the previous dates...

You can take look of [Jquery Date Picker API (minDate)](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Hope it may help you...

Comment: i wonder why that line of code disables the datepicker.. it just becomes an ordinary textfield

Comment: Because it's not necessary every time we need to disable previous date (in Most cases).. my answer worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried previous answers but nothing worked.
Here is how i solved this

1. The minDate is not found in the documentations https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
2. There is something like minDate no it's called startDate but it accepts only Date.
3. startDate Date. Default: Beginning of time The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled. as in Offical documentations.

So here you go.

```
     <?php
        $now = new DateTime();
        echo $form->field($data['model'], 'expire_date' ,
             ['template' =>
            '{label}<p class="sub-label">' . \Yii::t("main","After this date people won't be able to bid on this job no more.").'</p> {input}{error}{hint}'])
            ->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(),
             [            
            'options' => [
                'placeholder' => \Yii::t("main","Enter a date..."),
                'autoComplete' => 'off',
        
            ],
            //'convertFormat' => true,
            'language' => "Yii::$app->language;",
        
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'autoclose'=>true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
                'startDate' => date_format($now, 'Y-m-d'), //startDate Date. Default: Beginning of time The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.
            ]
        ]);?>
```

Comment: If you want to disable the future date use endDate instead of startDate

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your options array should help.

```
minDate: new Date(),
```